# How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?

Tags: postgresql, query, date, date-format, date-math

There is a `timestamp` column I use to indicate whether a row was created during day or night time. My code is the following, but for some reason I  only get 'DAY' as outcome. Am I not formatting the values right?

```
select record_id, rec_date,
       case when date_part('hour', rec_date) between 20 and 07 then 'Night'
            else 'Day' end as Indicator
from records;
```

The `rec_date` column is a timestamp where I can see values such as `2019-11-20 21:34:02.000000` - which should get a `'Night'` indicator.

Comment: What's the exact type of your timestamp variable? `timestamp` or `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`)? And is it really a *variable* or a *table column*? (I assume column from the context.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT record_id, rec_date
     , CASE WHEN rec_date::time <  '08:00' THEN 'Night'
            WHEN rec_date::time >= '20:00' THEN 'Night'
            ELSE 'Day' END AS indicator
FROM  records;
```

#### Why?

It's a matter of [date-math](/questions/tagged/date-math) rather than [date-format](/questions/tagged/date-format). You want to do the math correctly and efficiently. The format of 'Day' and 'Night' are not in question.

McNets already shed some light on `BETWEEN` vs. `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC`. But `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 20 AND 07` would still be **dead ugly, slow, and incorrect**, ultimately.

1. `SYMMETRIC` only makes sense with parameterized bounds where you don't know which will be greater ahead of time. Not the case, `20` and `07` are constants.
2. Applied to your case naively, you would get day and night inverted, because `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 20 AND 07` ends up being evaluated as `BETWEEN 07 AND 20` (just more expensively).
3. OK, easily fixed by switching 'Day' and 'Night'. But now, the times 20:** and 07:** would be tagged 'Day'. `BETWEEN`, with or without `SYMMETRIC`, includes upper *and* lower bound. That's why it is [**almost always the wrong tool** to use with timestamps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29). In this particular case, `date_part()` happens to counter the built-in issue with including both bounds to some extent. Either way, to match your original intent, it would have to be:

   ```
   CASE WHEN date_part('hour', ts) BETWEEN '08' AND '19'  -- adjusted
        THEN 'Day' ELSE 'Night' END AS indicator
   ```
4. The query with the expression `date_part('hour', rec_date) BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 20 AND 07` is roughly twice as **expensive** as my suggestion. The larger part due to the pointless `SYMMETRIC`, the smaller part due to the function being more expensive than the cast.
5. The suggested expression is much less likely to be misunderstood than the devious `BETWEEN`, as it makes clear which bounds are included.

#### Asides

I would not call a timestamp column "record_date", as `date` is a different basic data type than `timestamp`. More potential for confusion.

If your actual data type happens to be `timestamptz` (or, possibly, in any case), you may have to define *where* in the world it's supposed to be  "day" or "night". See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Answer (score 4):

According to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) BETWEEN transforms into:

> a BETWEEN x AND y
>
> is equivalent to
>
> a >= x AND a <= y

That means that x must be lesser than y.

Also in the docs you can find there is a BETWEEN SYMMETRIC, that can help in your question.

> BETWEEN SYMMETRIC is like BETWEEN except there is no requirement that
>   the argument to the left of AND be less than or equal to the argument
>   on the right. If it is not, those two arguments are automatically
>   swapped, so that a nonempty range is always implied.

> ```
> create table test (id int);
> insert into test values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
>
> select id from test where id between symmetric 4 and 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=27c46a2dc5cd03a851552eb8520426f3)*

Comment: I was totally blind to that! Thank you. That is my new query, working perfectly fine: ```select record_id, rec_date,
case when date_part('hour', rec_date) between 08 and 20 then 'Day'
           else 'Night' end as Indicator
from records```

Comment: That is great, I will apply the between symmetric. Thank you very much!