# Group by time interval and output the source and destination station_id and count

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am stuck with a query:

```
CREATE TABLE public.bulk_sample (
    serial_number character varying(255),
    validation_date timestamp,  -- timestamp of entry and exit
    station_id integer,
    direction integer           -- 1 = Entry | 2 = Exit
);

INSERT INTO public.bulk_sample VALUES
  ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 08:31:58', 120, 1)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 08:50:22', 113, 2)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 10:16:56', 113, 1)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 10:47:06', 120, 2)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 16:02:12', 120, 1)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 16:47:45', 102, 2)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 19:26:38', 102, 1)
, ('019b5526970fcfcf7813e9fe1acf8a41bcaf5a5a5c10870b3211d82f63fbf270', '2020-02-01 20:17:24', 120, 2)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 07:58:20', 119, 1)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 08:43:35', 104, 2)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 16:38:10', 104, 1)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 17:15:01', 119, 2)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 17:42:29', 119, 1)
, ('23cc9678e8cf834decb096ba36be0efee418402bce03aab52e69026adfec7663', '2020-02-01 17:48:05', 120, 2)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 15:17:59', 120, 1)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 15:25:25', 118, 2)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 16:16:12', 118, 1)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 16:32:51', 120, 2)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 19:31:20', 120, 1)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 19:39:33', 118, 2)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 20:57:50', 118, 1)
, ('2a8f28bf0afc655210aa337aff016d33100282ac73cca660a397b924808499af', '2020-02-01 21:16:25', 120, 2)
;
```

I have to create a query which gives a result as follows

```
source | dest | Count
120    | 113  |  1
113    | 120  |  1
```

I tried the following code but not able to get the desired result:

```
SELECT serial_number
     , count(*)
     , min(validation_date) AS start_time
     , CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN max(validation_date) END AS end_time
FROM  (
   SELECT serial_number, validation_date, count(step OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY serial_number, 
validation_date) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , lag(validation_date) OVER (PARTITION BY serial_number ORDER BY validation_date)
           < validation_date - interval '60 min' AS step
      FROM   table1 
       where BETWEEN '2020-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-01 23:59:59'
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY serial_number, grp;
```

The time interval is about 55 mins to 60 mins between every entry and exit.

I have also tried an inner join but not able to group by the time interval in an inner join

```
SELECT source.station_id AS source_station ,dest.station_id AS destination_station ,source.count FROM 
    (
        SELECT serial_number,station_id,count(bulk_transaction_id) FROM table1
        WHERE 
            direction = 1 AND 
            validation_date BETWEEN '2020-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-01 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY serial_number,station_id
    )source

 INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT serial_number,station_id,count(bulk_transaction_id) FROM table1
        WHERE 
            direction = 2 AND 
            validation_date BETWEEN '2020-02-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-01 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY serial_number,station_id
    )dest
ON source.serial_number = dest.serial_number and source.station_id <> dest.station_id
```

The challenge is sometimes there is null in entry date and sometimes there is null in exit date.

Comment: Could you please provide your table structure as DDL and your data as DML? Help us to help you!

Comment: Hi Verace, Thank You for your response, I have edited the query as per your comment.

Comment: Hi McNets, As you can see in the inner join query I have to get the source, destination, and count from the table and generate a Pivot Table with the result.

Comment: I seem to recognize my SQL style in your queries. So I guess you started with code from a related answer? It would help to link to your source.

Comment: `The challenge is sometimes there is null in entry date and sometimes there is null in exit date.` Then how to determine the corresponding entry/exit? If there are multiple rows with `validation_date IS NULL` for the same `serial_number`, the information can quickly become ambiguous. Also, can transaction time ranges overlap? If so, what is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simplest and fastest while **transactions per `serial_number` never overlap**:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT serial_number, validation_date, station_id, direction
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY serial_number ORDER BY validation_date) AS rn
   FROM   bulk_sample
   WHERE  validation_date >= '2020-02-01'  -- ①
   AND    validation_date <  '2020-02-02'  -- entry & exit must be within time frame
   )
SELECT s.station_id AS source, d.station_id AS dest, count(*)
FROM   cte s
JOIN   cte d USING (serial_number)
WHERE  s.direction = 1
AND    d.rn = s.rn + 1
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;  -- optional sort order
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a3c9bb5fc27b7ccc418304f76fdc5da)*

① I rewrote the `WHERE` condition to get all of Feb 1 2020 in optimal fashion. [`BETWEEN` is almost always the wrong tool for time ranges](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29). See:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267869/how-to-add-a-day-night-indicator-to-a-timestamp-column/267877#267877)

Also, '2020-02-01' is a perfectly valid `timestamp` constant `00:00:00` is assumed when the time component is missing.

While retrieving results for a given time frame, a plain btree **index** on `(validation_date)` is the optimum. For the complete table, an index on `(serial_number, validation_date)` would help more.

#### `validation_date IS NULL`?

The query keeps working while only the *last* destination per `serial_number` in the given time frame has `validation_date IS NULL` because `NULL` values happen to sort last in default ascending order. But it breaks with any other cases of `validation_date IS NULL`. You'll have to define more closely where those can pop up and how to deal with them exactly.

#### (2x) `uuid` instead of `varchar(255)` for `serial_number`?

Your `serial_number` seems to be a hexadecimal number with exactly 64 digits. If so, `varchar(255)` is a poor choice. See:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496)

Moreover, a single `uuid` (32 hex digits) should suffice. If all 64 hex digits are needed, still consider 2 `uuid` columns. Smaller, faster, safer. Consider:

```sql
SELECT *
     , replace(uuid1::text || uuid2::text, '-', '') AS reverse_engineered
     , replace(uuid1::text || uuid2::text, '-', '') = serial_number AS identical
     , pg_column_size(serial_number) AS varchar_size
     , pg_column_size(uuid1) + pg_column_size(uuid2) AS uuid_size
FROM  (
   SELECT serial_number
        , left(serial_number, 32)::uuid  AS uuid1
        , right(serial_number, 32)::uuid AS uuid2
   FROM   bulk_sample
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a3c9bb5fc27b7ccc418304f76fdc5da)*

See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @Erwin. I have added more data for analysis. Please do have a look in this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=520f79d3c4ebbd9d4a5489b787e5f849).

Comment: Hi, @Erwin your assumption is correct, the link which I referred is [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157595/how-to-get-minimum-and-maximum-for-grouped-timestamps). Your solution in the following link almost suited my requirement.

Comment: @DeepanKaviarasu: More data is good. Clarifying open question and assumptions would help even more.

Answer (score 2):

For this you will need two things:

1. A correlated subquery on your join condition
2. An unique index on (serial_number,validation_date)

After that, your query becomes:

```
SELECT
  station_entry.station_id AS source
 ,station_exit.station_id AS dest
 ,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  public.bulk_sample station_entry
INNER JOIN
  public.bulk_sample station_exit
    ON station_exit.serial_number = station_entry.serial_number
        AND station_exit.validation_date =
              (
                SELECT
                  MIN(validation_date)
                FROM
                  public.bulk_sample
                WHERE
                  serial_number = station_entry.serial_number
                    AND validation_date > station_entry.validation_date
              )
WHERE
  station_entry.direction = 1
    AND station_exit.direction = 2  --Ensure next transaction is valid
    AND station_entry.validation_date >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00'
    AND station_entry.validation_date <= '2020-02-01 23:59:59'
    AND station_exit.validation_date <= '2020-02-01 23:59:59' --Ensure both events occurred within specified timeframe
GROUP BY
  station_entry.station_id
 ,station_exit.station_id
```

Should return:

```
source  dest    count
102     120     1
104     119     1
113     120     1
118     120     2
119     104     1
119     120     1
120     102     1
120     113     1
120     118     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This saved me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @DeepanKaviarasu, glad to help.  Thankfully your table layout lent itself to the easiest possible solution.